# Вложенный tqdm, pretty print

Tags: python, windows, pycharm, progress-bar

Как сделать так, чтобы K уровней tqdm-ов выписывалось ровно в K строчек?

Пример:

```
from tqdm import tqdm
from time import sleep

for _ in tqdm(range(5), "All", ncols=80, position=0):
    for _ in tqdm(range(100), "Sub", ncols=80, position=1, leave=False):
        sleep(0.01)
```

Выводит:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А ожидаю только 2 строчки `All` и `Sub`.

Перепробовал разные комбинации параметров. Иногда в песочнице в браузере работает, а на винде локально -- нет. Модуль `colorama` не помог тоже.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
from tqdm.auto import tqdm
from time import sleep

for _ in tqdm(range(5), "All", position=0):
    for _ in tqdm(range(100), "Sub", position=1, leave=False):
        sleep(0.01)
```

Т.е. во-первых используйте `tqdm.auto`, он лучше определяет как оптимально общаться с конкретно вашим типом устройства вывода. И во-вторых уберите параметр `ncols`, он может мешать нормальному позиционированию элементов прогресс-бара.

Comment: Это решение работате в песочнице, но мне не поможет, потому что https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm/issues/203

Answer (score 2):

Короче PyCharm-овский терминал на винде не поддерживает такое. Чтобы получить правильный вывод, надо поставить *"Emulate terminal in output console"* флажок или ждать, когда добавят поддержку. С этим флажком достаточно только `leave=False` во втором поставить.